# Change foreground color of ComboBoxItem when ComboBox is hovered

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

At the moment, I'm styling WPF controls. This is how my custom `<Button>` looks hovered.

[image: button]

And this is how `<ComboBox>` looks when mouse is over it.

[image: combobox]

Simply, I want  to be able to change foreground color of currently selected `ComboBoxItem` when whole ComboBox is hovered. In this example, I'd like to have similiar yellow color like on `<Button>` control.

The problem is, that `<ComboBox>` has different ControlTemplates for ComboBox item and toggle button. I don't know how to interact between those two.

The template for `<ComboBox>` is pretty big, so I'm not going to post it here. Also, you don't have to post full answer if it's not required to explain the problem.

Comment: Can't you just add another setter to your trigger?

Comment: Like @Okuma.Scott said, just throw like `<Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Yellow" />` in your IsHighlighted or whatever trigger, or you could just [read the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.comboboxitem.ishighlighted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: "The template for <ComboBox> is pretty big, so I'm not going to post it here" If you want a code answer, post the code following [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a solution. You need to edit default ComboBox templates.

In Visual Studio 2013 you can get a default template in Designer by clicking right mouse button on ComboBox -> Edit template -> Edit a copy...

In `<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">` you have to add a following trigger:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
...
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" TargetName="toggleButton" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="Yellow" />
</Trigger>
...
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Also, apply a style to ComboBoxItem:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
</Style>
```

Now, it works like a charm.